# Can't getting the implementation of __repr__() method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods, tuples

I was reading the famous book on python named 'python cookbook' by David Beazley and Brian K. Jones. In their 'classes and objects' chapter, they have written the following code:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point({0.x!r}, {0.y!r})'.format(self)
    def __str__(self):
        return '({0.x!s}, {0.y!s})'.format(self)
```

Now, only I got to understand that the **repr**() method is used to represent an object to a developer and **str**() to a blind user. But in both the methods, what is being happened after 'return'? There are tuples in both cases for sure. But what kinda member the tuples have? I haven't seen anything like this before.

Comment: look carefully, both functions return formatted strings, not tuples

Comment: Okay true, but how's the whole thing working?

Comment: its just returning a string. Thats all

Comment: Yeah, but what are those {0.x!r} and all? Can't decode the meaning.

Comment: @SaswataMishra that's just string formatting, it has nothing to do with these methods, and you should ask a different question about them

Comment: @SaswataMishra [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) cover this in great detail.

Comment: Those are just formatting place holders. that tell how to format/present the variables passed o the format method. you can look up the formting mini language in the python docs https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec

Answer (score 2):

Both `__repr__` and `__str__` in your example return formatted strings, not tuples. These functions are called when either `repr()` or `str()` is called on the object, explicitly or implicitly.

For example, a `print(Point(1,2))` would print the result of `__str__` because it calls `str()` on the object internally, but `print([Point(1,2)])` would print the result of `__repr__` instead.

For your own objects, these methods can return anything you want, just as long as those are just strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a breakdown of the specific [formatting syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). With the `str.format` method you can fill-in placeholders in the given string instance that are of the form `{...}`. These work with positional arguments in the following way:

```
>>> '{}:{}'.format(1, 2)
'1:2'
>>> '{0}:{1}'.format(1, 2)
'1:2'
>>> '{1}:{0}'.format(1, 2)
'2:1'
```

That means you can specify the number of the positional argument inside the curly braces. The string can refer to a positional argument multiple times:

```
>>> '{0}:{1}:{0}'.format(1, 2)
'1:2:1'
```

Using `.x` notation let's you access attributes of that argument. For example:

```
>>> class Test:
...     x = 1
...     y = 2
... 
>>> '{0.x}:{0.y}'.format(Test)
'1:2'
```

Using `!r` you can force to use the `__repr__` of that object rather than the `__str__`. For example:

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __str__(self):
...         return '__str__'
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return '__repr__'
... 
>>> '{0}'.format(Test())
'__str__'
>>> '{0!s}'.format(Test())
'__str__'
>>> '{0!r}'.format(Test())
'__repr__'
```

So combining all this information we get the following:

```
'Point({0.x!r}, {0.y!r})'.format(self)
```

Here a format string with two placeholders is defined (`{0.x!r}` and `{0.y!r}`). They should be filled in with the first positional argument's `x` and `y` attributes (recall that `{0}` will be substituted with the first argument, so `{0.x}` requests the `x` attribute of that argument). And finally the `!r` requests the `__repr__` of that object rather than the `__str__` (which is the default).

The same reasoning applies to the `__str__` method.

By the way, the formatting syntax also allows keyword arguments and they can be referred to by their name:

```
>>> '{first}:{second}'.format(first=1, second=2)
'1:2'
>>> '{second}:{first}'.format(first=1, second=2)
'2:1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this in an interpreter to see what is going on:

```
>>> class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """Initialize self."""
        self.x, self.y = x, y
    def __repr__(self):
        """Return repr(self)."""
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.x!r}, {self.y!r})'
    def __str__(self):
        """Return str(self)."""
        return f'({self.x!s}, {self.y!s})'

>>> Point(1, 2) # causes implicit call to __repr__
Point(1, 2)
>>> print(_) # causes implicit call to __str__
(1, 2)
>>>
```